# Wordpress: Displaying article for every minute

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible to loop all you post and display one single post with excerpt, title and featured image per minute? just like any advertisement. They're displaying one advertisement and it keeps on changing for a certain period of time.

TIA!

Comment: Interesting you ask this question. I wrote a plugin 1.5 years ago to do *exactly* this. Unfortunately I can't give you the code because it was written and paid for by a customer.

Comment: @DannyBeckett, I ask this question because I want to try cross promoting to other websites for free so I might gain traffic because my domain is new. Thank you

Comment: You can do a WordPress query to retrieve all the posts you will want to display, but set the posts to display:none in the CSS.  Then use javascript's setInterval() function to display one post per minute.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> pest code when you define your banner post:
> ```
>
> index.php(you define code on your page define name and replace
>   index.php)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        setInterval(function(){
            $('#load_tweets').load('index.php #load_tweets', function() {
            $('#load_tweets').fadeOut('fast').load('mybanner.php').fadeIn("slow");
            });
        },60000);
</script>

<?php require_once (TEMPLATEPATH . '/mybanner.php'); ?>


mybanner.php

<div id="load_tweets">
        <?php
        query_posts(array('orderby' => 'rand', 'showposts' => 1));
        if (have_posts()) :
        while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>

        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'thumbnail'); ?>    

        <?php endwhile;
        endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Ravi, thank you but I need to use the script outside my website. Since the script is tied to my location then it won't work.